# How did we use Localization in Abp.Theme project , while localization Sources in Domain.shared?

Tags: asp.net, n-tier-architecture, abp

In Razor Pages, we incorporate the `@inject IHtmlLocalizer<ContractResource> L` in the WEB Project.

> How do we apply localization in the Abp.Theme project when the localization sources reside in Domain.shared?

Is it necessary to inject Domain.shared into the Theme Project? What would be the most effective approach for implementing ABP in this scenario?

Comment: Please add more information which template do you use, which ABP version ? Basically you could check the documentation about localization here -> https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Localization. You can use Ihtmllocalizer for razor pages or IStringLocalizer for backend

Answer (score 0):

To use localization In ABP, Initially, a class is created in the `Domain.Shared` layer with a name suffixed by "Resource" and adorned with the `LocalizationResourceName` attribute. Subsequently, this class is registered in the configuration of within the relevant module.

```
// Example: Configuring localization in a module
Configure<AbpLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Resources
        .Add<MyResource>("en")
        .AddDefault();
});
```

Once these steps are completed, localization can be utilized in Razor pages of ABP by employing the `Microsoft.Extensions.Localization` namespace and injecting the `IStringLocalizer` interface. The following command is then used to enable localization within Razor pages:

```cs
@inject IStringLocalizer<MyResource> L
```

Here, `LearnResource` corresponds to the class created in the `Domain.Shared` layer.